# With $G=S_{5}$ acting on $X$ by conjugation, prove $|X|=10$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

Multiple problems, that don't all fit in the title.

> Let $G=S_{5}$ and let $X=\{H \leq G: |H| =3 \}$. It is given that $G$ acts on $X$ by conjugation, so by mapping $(g,H)$ in $G \times X$ to $gHg^{-1}= \{ ghg^{-1} \text{ with } h \text{ in } H \}$ in $X$.
>
> **Problem 1.** Prove $|X|=10$ and that all elements of $X$ are in the same orbit for this action.
>
> **Problem 2.** Let $\sigma=(123)$ and $H= \langle \sigma \rangle$. Explain why $F=N_{G}(H)$ is a subgroup with $12$ elements and give $F$ in the form $\langle f_{1}, f_{2} \rangle$.

First of all, I find it hard to even understand what exactly is asked. Since $|H|$ has only three elements and is a subgroup of $G$, I would argue that one of the three elements in the identity, leaving only two options per subgroup $H$. Also I know there are exactly $20$ elements of order $3$ in $G$, namely all the permutations of the $3$ cycle (which has $\frac{5!}{3!}=20$ options).

This is all I have got, any hints are appreciated.

Comment: What you wrote already establishes the first part of Q1.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there are $20$ elements of order $3$. Now, each subgroup of order $3$ contains exactly two elements of order $3$. More than that, any two distinct subgroups of order $3$ intersect trivially, this follows from Lagrange's theorem. So that way we get that $S_5$ has exactly $10$ subgroups of order $3$. Now why all such subgroups are in the same orbit? That is because here subgroups of order $3$ are actually $3$-Sylow subgroups of $S_5$, hence by Sylow theorems they are all conjugate to each other.

Comment: If I get you right, since we know $H$ has three elements and we know the order of the elements divide the grouporder, we also know the elements have order $3$. Since they are all subgroups, only two elements besides the identity remain in the subgroup. So I get why there are $20$ options for $H$. And since each group contains the inverses of its elements, any two subgroup $H$ has an equal other subgroup $H$ (this is not a very nice sentence but I hope you know what I mean).  I am not familiar with Sylow, and in the book I follow he isn't mentioned yet, so I was hoping on a proof without him.

Comment: Well, this is an equivalent way of saying that. You can also think of it like that: any subgroup of order $3$ has the form $\{id,\sigma,\sigma^{-1}\}$ when $\sigma\in S_5$ is an element of order $3$. From here it is easy to see that there are $10$ such subgroups.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint for problem $2$:** For the conjugation action of $G=S_5$ on $X$,  use the orbit-stabilizer theorem.   Note that $N_G(H)$ is the stabilizer of $H$.

Now, $N_G(H)=\langle (123), (234)\rangle $, as $(234)=(14)(123)(14)$ is a conjugate of $(123)$.  (The subgroup $(123)$ and $(234)$ generate has order $12$.)

Comment: How did you find $(234)$, is that just trial and error or do you use some kind of algorithm to find it? Also, it is not obvious to me that $(123)$ and $(234)$ generate a subgroup of order $12$. I know the order of two disjoint cycles it the least common multiplier of the order of those two cycles, but these cycles are not disjoint. Since the order of both is $3$ I feel tempted to say the order of the product is simple $9$ but this is obviously false. Any hints?

Comment: Well, like i said i took a conjugate of $(123)$.  I don't think it's that obvious that they generate the whole normalizer.  But, on the other hand,  it's fairly easy to establish that there are more than $6$ distinct element.   Since we know the normalizer has $12$ elements,  we can conclude that they generate the whole thing.

Comment: Ah, so you just took an arbitrary conjugate! Make sense, thanks.